# How are PHPDoc comments analyzed in PHP?

Tags: php, phpdoc

In frameworks like Zend Framework (or extensions of it), it is sometimes possible to pass information like type hints to the framework code by using PHPDoc style comments.

I cannot imagine that the framework parses the files using PHP, but I do not see any other way to achieve this, except for some built-in language feature of PHP, which I don't know of. So how is this done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They use [reflection](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php) and especially [`ReflectionMethod::getDocComment()`](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/reflectionfunctionabstract.getdoccomment.php) (there is also [`ReflectionClass::getDocComment()`](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getdoccomment.php), [`ReflectionProperty::getDocComment()`](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/reflectionproperty.getdoccomment.php) and [`ReflectionFunction::getDocComment()`](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/reflectionfunctionabstract.getdoccomment.php)). The rest is simple: just parse the doc-block with some regular expressions or something like that.

Comment: Cool. Thank you very much. Didn't know that the reflection class went that far. Any other cool features I missed out on?